# Problem when submit a form with select tag helper asp.net core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to use select tag helper to choose a role for creating account in my web app.

The following is my code

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var model = new AccountCreateViewModel()
        {
            Roles = new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name").ToList()
        };

        return View(model);
    }
```

The following is the code in view of the select.

```
<div class="form-floating">
    <select asp-for="RoleId" asp-items="@Model.Roles" class="form-select"></select>
    <label asp-for="RoleId"></label>
    <span asp-validation-for="RoleId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" />
```

The following is my model

```
public class AccountCreateViewModel
{
    public RegisterModel.InputModel Input { get; set; } = new();

    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; } = null;

    [StringLength(80)]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Role")]
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    
    public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

However, after I submit the form, then the controller check the model state, and it is invalid. I have debugged and all the fields is valid except Roles.
So, someone can give me a solution for this situation?

[model state debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HNEC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply [`[ValidateNever]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.validation.validateneverattribute?view=aspnetcore-6.0) attribute to remove validate of the `Roles` on the server side. When applied to a property, the validation system excludes that property.

```cs
public class AccountCreateViewModel
{
    ...
    [ValidateNever]
    public List<SelectListItem> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider that a `SelectList` takes an object of type `IEnumerable` as the first argument in the constructor. Make sure that you give it an `IEnumerable` or `List` in this section:

```
Roles = new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles, "Id", "Name").ToList()
```

This code may help you:

```
Roles = new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles.ToList(), "Id", "Name")
```

If `_roleManager.Roles` returns an `IEnumerable` or `List`, you don't need the `.ToList()`

Comment: basically, the reason I use `.ToList()` is the data type of Roles is `List<SelectListItem>`. I follow the tutorial in Microsoft Docs for select in Forms. For a question, is 'SelectList' work with`asp-items` in 'select' tag helper?

Comment: So, if `_roleManager.Roles` returns a `List`, it is not necessary to use `.ToList()`. The `select` tag heler works with `asp-items`.